# JS formatting error: "Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token )"

Tags: javascript, jquery

So im trying to write some script for a modal that im using on my site. And I applied this script in the header which is needed for it to function and this is the error I get in the search console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

this is my code:

```
<script>
  function() {
    $("#modal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
      var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
      $(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
    });
  };
</script>
```

It looks fine to me... what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Indentation makes it easier for others to read your code. And for you to, too. :-) See Rory's edit.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Im just trying to learn here.

Answer (score 7):

That's a function declaration without a name. Function declarations must have names.

You may have meant it to be an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript), in which case add `(` in front of it and `)()` at the end before the `;`:

```
(function(){
    $("#modal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
        var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
        $(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
    });
})();
```

Or if you meant to use jQuery's "DOM ready" functionality, you may have meant to pass that function into `$()`, in which case put `$(` in front of it and `)` at the end before the `;`:

```
$(function(){
    $("#modal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
        var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
        $(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
    });
});
```

Those work because function *expressions* don't have to have names. When the JavaScript parser is expecting a statement and sees `function`, it assumes that's a function declaration. But when it's expecting an *expression*, not a statement, it knows it's a function expression instead.

Comment: I don't have any training in JS or development, these are basically bits of code I have scraped together from others and only marginally understand the underlying concept. However after some more reasearch I found that Joomla my CMS requires the use of jQuery in place of $ and that did the trick.

Comment: Changing `$` to `jQuery` in your original code won't do it. But yes, some CMSs (Joomla, Wordpress) require that you use `jQuery` instead of `$` (normally you can use either). So that *combined* with one of the two suggestions above should work.

Comment: Yeah that was needed to make the difference. It works now so its sovled.